# How to install php memcache in a production server?

Tags: php, linux

Is there any way to install memcache without pecl/phpize ?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.installation.php

It's a production server, its a good practice to install pecl/phpize into it ?

Comment: Any popular Linux distribution should provide binaries for memcache. Check software repository of your server Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have complete control over the server it's not hard to install at all — and it's not a big deal to install pecl on a production server, that's a standard method of installing php packages — your server should be secure enough for it to not matter.

As for whether there's a way to do it without pecl — if you're running a distro like Ubuntu there's a package made just for you : php5-memcache

**References:**

[installing-memcached-on-ubuntu-for-php](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/02/08/installing-memcached-on-ubuntu-for-php/)

Comment: great, but it is a RHEL5, i'll serch for that

Comment: @Fusion: http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/English-site-introduction

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to install memcache without pecl/phpize ?

Yes, you can use pre-made binaries.

> It's a production server, its a good practice to install pecl/phpize into it ?

Best practice is to use a tested system that is managed and that has a repository from which to checkout tested binaries.